# How to turn this into an alias?

Tags: linux, alias, grep

I frequently use this command:

grep -rnw donkey | grep market | cut -c -80

How can I change it into an alias on Linux?

I tried:

```
alias search='grep -rnw $1 | grep $2 | cut -c -200'
```

But when I run it with

```
search hello world
```

it gives me:

```
cut: Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
hello: No such file or directory
cut: Try 'grep --help' for more information.
world: No such file or directory
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/1352083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, bash alias doesn't accept parameters like some other shells.

But you can get around it by declaring search as a function which you can add to your `.bashrc` file

```
function search { grep -rnw $1 | grep $2 | cut -c -200; }
export -f search
```

See: [Make bash alias that takes a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)

In the link the example uses an alias which seems to be unessessary. 
You can put the function with `export -f` search directly into `.bashrc` and name the function as search.

If all else fails another option is to write a script called search.

e.g.  create a script named `search` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -rnw $1 | grep $2 | cut -c -200;
```

Place this somewhere in a path defined in `$PATH` like /usr/bin or
perhaps $HOME/bin.  If using $HOME/bin put that path in your environment like.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Comment: THanks, but I get the same error. I am on Debian:

Comment: Works on Ubuntu.  I only get that error if no parameters are provided.  It would be prudent to make the function more robust to missing parameters though.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. In my excitement I didn't read that I had to add it to .bashrc

Comment: @Matt how would you do it for Mac? I am on mac I have the same use case of grep command.

Comment: @ShaileshSutar - maybe the same way, or if it doesn't work use a script.  See updated answer.